# Can’t render fluid simulations….?

Tags: rendering, fluid-simulation

Me again. There are lots of tutorials on fluid simulations but none on how to render them, LOL! I’m obviously missing something. When I try to render all I see is the domain cube! If I turn off the domain cube from rendering I can see what’s within but no fluid simulation. What’s up? Using Eevee.

Rusty

Answer (score 1):

two major things to control:

- did you bake the meshes? (you need to bake data to simulate the fluid and then bake mesh to create the water shapes)
- did you create a new material for the "liquid domain"? (default one generated by quick effect is not good for eevee) check for "water shader nodes in eevee" tutorials